# SQL Server 2008 Merge Statement

Tags: sql-server, merge

I tried several times to execute the following `MERGE` statement, but I always got the same error message:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.

Any idea why this error?

```
    CREATE TABLE StudentDetails
    (
        StudentID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        StudentName VARCHAR(15)
    )
    GO

    INSERT INTO StudentDetails
    VALUES(1,'SMITH')
    INSERT INTO StudentDetails
    VALUES(2,'ALLEN')
    INSERT INTO StudentDetails
    VALUES(3,'JONES')
    INSERT INTO StudentDetails
    VALUES(4,'MARTIN')
    INSERT INTO StudentDetails
    VALUES(5,'JAMES')
    GO

    CREATE TABLE StudentTotalMarks
    (
        StudentID INTEGER REFERENCES StudentDetails,
        StudentMarks INTEGER
    )
    GO

    INSERT INTO StudentTotalMarks
    VALUES(1,230)
    INSERT INTO StudentTotalMarks
    VALUES(2,255)
    INSERT INTO StudentTotalMarks
    VALUES(3,200)
    GO

    MERGE StudentTotalMarks AS stm
    USING (SELECT StudentID,StudentName FROM StudentDetails) AS sd
    ON stm.StudentID = sd.StudentID
    WHEN MATCHED AND stm.StudentMarks > 250 THEN DELETE
    WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET stm.StudentMarks = stm.StudentMarks + 25
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT(StudentID,StudentMarks)
    VALUES(sd.StudentID,25);
```

Comment: In future, please format your code, so we can read it.

Comment: The code provided works fine, no syntax errors.

Answer (score 3):

**Your code works exactly as written for me.**

Are you sure you are using `SQL Server 2008`?

Comment: I don't understand what happens in my case, I do use SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: @largo - Is your Management Studio 2008 AND your server/database?  It's possible to connect to an older database or older server from a newer SSMS version.

Answer (score 1):

You need SQL Server 2008 to use [merge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx).

I have modified your code to use table variables instead just to prove that it works in SQL Server 2008.

You can test it here: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/105423/test-merge

Comment: @JNK - yes it does but the error message is from SQL Server 2005 not recognizing `merge`. His code is correct as it is.

Comment: I got that after I posted the comment when the code worked for me :)

Comment: @JNK - BTW, this merge statement used here is ignorant to compatibility level settings.

Comment: @largo68 - Are you sure your DB is 2008 not only SQL Server Managment Studio 2008? What does this tell you? `select @@version`

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server  2000 - 8.00.2282 (Intel X86)   Dec 30 2008 02:22:41   Copyright (c) 1988-2003 Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition on Windows NT 5.2 (Build 3790: Service Pack 2)

Comment: @largo - Perhaps you had a 2000 installed earlier and your 2008 installed on the side with a differently named instance.